# CodeIgniter Database query limit

Tags: codeigniter

I'm doing some db querys using ActiveRecord and i need to paginate the results so i do a

```
$this->db->limit($pPagination['Start'], $pPagination['Length']);
```

but i don't get any results. Using `$this->db->last_query();` it seems that CodeIgniter  produces the following SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM (`viw_contacts`)
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
ORDER BY `contact_name` asc
LIMIT 0 OFFSET 15
```

which when i run it inside PHPMyAdmin also returns 0 rows.

But if i modify it an run :

```
SELECT *
FROM (`viw_contacts`)
WHERE `user_id` = '1'
ORDER BY `contact_name` asc
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Then i get the correct results. Any ideea why CodeIgniter generates this SQL and why it doesn't work?

I use CodeIgniter 1.7.3 and MySQL 5.1.41

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, found the issue.

It's

```
$this->db->limit($pPagination['Length'], $pPagination['Start']);
```

instead of

```
$this->db->limit($pPagination['Start'], $pPagination['Length']);
```

First param is the Length and second is the offset, not the other way around as i thought.