# How to get the first data from an array

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have the following code in my codeigniter's view file.

```
<?php foreach ($records as $rows){?>
 <?  echo $rows['product_name']; ?> <br>
 <? } ?>
```

my model

```
 $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->order_by('product_name','ASC');
        $getData = $this->db->get('');
        if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
        return $getData->result_array();
        else
        return null;
```

If I run the above code I get the following result

```
    Pepsi
    Coke
    Mountain Dew
```

I am trying to show only the first result (Pepsi). Could you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$records is an Array. You can specify the index like

```
<?=$records[0]['product_name']?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` to tell the DB to pull only a limited number of records from the database

```
$this->db->from('products LIMIT 0,1');
```

Comment: I cannot limit the query, because I need other information in my same view file. Is it possible without limiting the query? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$query = $this->db->limit(0, 1);
```

See doc: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

See also: [CodeIgniter Database query limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889869/codeigniter-database-query-limit)

Comment: I cannot limit the query, because I need other information in my same view file. Is it possible without limiting the query? Thanks

Comment: Then you could use method `row()` on the results, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280235/code-igniter-return-only-one-row

Answer (score 0):

reset is another solution to this problem.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

so in the example, 
$first_element = reset($records);